# polynomial, reed solomon

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Please advise if somebody knows:

The polynomial x^2+x+2 ∈ **F**3^2is irreducible and i am looking for the generator polynomial, the length and dimension.

What i did its: 
Find the vector-exponent equivalence for each element 
0-> (0,0)
a->(0,1)
a^2->(1,2)
a^3->(2,2)
a^4->(2,0)
a^5->(0,2)
a^6->(2,1)
a^7->(1,1)
a^8->(1,0)

the generator g(x) can be obtained assuming that a, a^2,a^3 are within its roots, so the g(x)=(x-a)(x-a^2)(x-a^3).
And when i multiply (x-a)(x-a^2)(x-a^3), i get few elements but i am not sure if the generator polynomial is the result or i need to do something more.

thanks

Comment: polynomial in  **F**3^2? What does it mean?

Comment: Do you mean $x^2+x+2\in \mathbb F_{3^2}[x]$?  Also, what's a "generator polynomial"?

Comment: yes, i mean that.
There is one and only one nonzero code polynomial (or code vector) of minimum degree
(n-k) in a (n, k) cyclic code. This polynomial is called generator polynomial and is of the
form g(x) = 1 + g1x + g2x^2 + + gn-k-1x^n-k-1 + x^n-k